# Functions in another .cpp file

Tags: c++, string, function

Okay, so I've been struggling with header files and making my functions work properly. I have 2 .cpp files and a header file.

main.cpp:

```
#include "Aliohjelmat.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const unsigned int MAX_LKM = 40; //globaali vakio

int main() {

string Opiskelija[MAX_LKM]; //Määritetään tarvittavat taulukot
int HarjMaara[MAX_LKM];
float Arvosana[MAX_LKM];
int laskuri = 0;
int toiminto = 0;
cout << "Valitse toiminto:" << endl << "1.Lisaa uusi opiskelija";
cin >> toiminto;
switch (toiminto) {
case '1':
    oppilas(Opiskelija, HarjMaara, Arvosana, laskuri);
    laskuri++;
    break;
default:
    cout << "Valitse oikea toiminto";
    break;
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Aliohjelmat.cpp

```
#include "Aliohjelmat.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void oppilas(string nimet[], int Tehtavat[], float Arvosanat[],int& laskuri){
cout << "Opiskelija nimi: ";
cin >> nimet[laskuri];
cout << "Tehdyt tehtavat (max. 40): ";
cin >> Tehtavat[laskuri];
cout << "Harjoitustyon arvosana: ";
cin >> Arvosanat[laskuri];
return;
}
```

And the header file, Aliohjelmat.h

```
void oppilas(string nimet[], int Tehtavat[], float Arvosanat[], int& laskuri);
```

My VS Community 15 is giving me 5 different errors, C2065: 'string': undeclared identifier. C3861 'oppilas': identifier not found, and others like those. I can get this work if I just put all the functions in the main.cpp and forgot about those 2 other files, but I want to get them to work. Also the files were working ok when I tried them with a simple int function.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't see how that could be possible, you've included string and have `using namespace std`.  Have you tried re-compiling?  Please give the full output and show us `Aliohjelmat.h`.

Comment: peter answered me. Thanks everyone for help tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function signature you showed in your post is the entire contents of Aliohjelmat.h, then you're seeing this error because the compiler doesn't know what `string` is by the time it gets there.

After the preprocessor is done with Aliohjelmat.cpp, it would look like this:

```
// expanded contents of Aliohjelmat.h:
void oppilas(string nimet[], int Tehtavat[], float Arvosanat[], int& laskuri);
// [expanded contents of iostream will be here]
// [expanded contents of string will be here]

using namespace std;

void oppilas(string nimet[], int Tehtavat[], float Arvosanat[],int& laskuri){
cout << "Opiskelija nimi: ";
cin >> nimet[laskuri];
cout << "Tehdyt tehtavat (max. 40): ";
cin >> Tehtavat[laskuri];
cout << "Harjoitustyon arvosana: ";
cin >> Arvosanat[laskuri];
return;
}
```

As you can see, the function `oppilas()` is declared before the contents of `<string>`, so the compiler doesn't know what the `string` type is at that point and complains about it.

You can fix this by either:

1. Moving `#include "Aliohjelmat.h"` down in the order of the includes to be after `#include <string>` and moving `using namespace std;` to be between `#include <string>` and `#include "Aliohjelmat.h"`; or
2. Adding `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;` to the top of `Aliohjelmat.h`.

Option 2 is the cleaner approach as it would allow you to use Aliohjelmat.h in any other cpp file without worrying about include order.